# Append senders email to the front of the attachment in Outlook using VBA

Tags: vba, email, outlook, email-attachments

I downloaded a script of VBA that I can use in my Outlook to save email attachment.

How can I edit this code so when I run the script it can append sender's email addresses to the front of the attachment name??

```
Option Explicit

' *****************
' For Outlook 2010.
' *****************
#If VBA7 Then
    ' The window handle of Outlook.
    Private lHwnd As LongPtr

    ' /* API declarations. */
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
        ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr

' *****************************************
' For the previous version of Outlook 2010.
' *****************************************
#Else
    ' The window handle of Outlook.
    Private lHwnd As Long

    ' /* API declarations. */
    Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
        ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
#End If

' The class name of Outlook window.
Private Const olAppCLSN As String = "rctrl_renwnd32"
' Windows desktop - the virtual folder that is the root of the namespace.
Private Const CSIDL_DESKTOP = &H0
' Only return file system directories. If the user selects folders that are not part of the file system, the OK button is grayed.
Private Const BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS = &H1
' Do not include network folders below the domain level in the dialog box's tree view control.
Private Const BIF_DONTGOBELOWDOMAIN = &H2
' The maximum length for a path is 260 characters.
Private Const MAX_PATH = 260

' ######################################################
'  Returns the number of attachements in the selection.
' ######################################################
Public Function SaveAttachmentsFromSelection() As Long
    Dim objFSO              As Object       ' Computer's file system object.
    Dim objShell            As Object       ' Windows Shell application object.
    Dim objFolder           As Object       ' The selected folder object from Browse for Folder dialog box.
    Dim objItem             As Object       ' A specific member of a Collection object either by position or by key.
    Dim selItems            As Selection    ' A collection of Outlook item objects in a folder.
    Dim atmt                As Attachment   ' A document or link to a document contained in an Outlook item.
    Dim strAtmtPath         As String       ' The full saving path of the attachment.
    Dim strAtmtFullName     As String       ' The full name of an attachment.
    Dim strAtmtName(1)      As String       ' strAtmtName(0): to save the name; strAtmtName(1): to save the file extension. They are separated by dot of an attachment file name.
    Dim strAtmtNameTemp     As String       ' To save a temporary attachment file name.
    Dim intDotPosition      As Integer      ' The dot position in an attachment name.
    Dim atmts               As Attachments  ' A set of Attachment objects that represent the attachments in an Outlook item.
    Dim lCountEachItem      As Long         ' The number of attachments in each Outlook item.
    Dim lCountAllItems      As Long         ' The number of attachments in all Outlook items.
    Dim strFolderPath       As String       ' The selected folder path.
    Dim blnIsEnd            As Boolean      ' End all code execution.
    Dim blnIsSave           As Boolean      ' Consider if it is need to save.

    blnIsEnd = False
    blnIsSave = False
    lCountAllItems = 0

    On Error Resume Next

    Set selItems = ActiveExplorer.Selection

    If Err.Number = 0 Then

        ' Get the handle of Outlook window.
        lHwnd = FindWindow(olAppCLSN, vbNullString)

        If lHwnd <> 0 Then

            ' /* Create a Shell application object to pop-up BrowseForFolder dialog box. */
            Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
            Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(lHwnd, "Select folder to save attachments:", _
                                                     BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS + BIF_DONTGOBELOWDOMAIN, CSIDL_DESKTOP)

            ' /* Failed to create the Shell application. */
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                MsgBox "Run-time error '" & CStr(Err.Number) & " (0x" & CStr(Hex(Err.Number)) & ")':" & vbNewLine & _
                       Err.Description & ".", vbCritical, "Error from Attachment Saver"
                blnIsEnd = True
                GoTo PROC_EXIT
            End If

            If objFolder Is Nothing Then
                strFolderPath = ""
                blnIsEnd = True
                GoTo PROC_EXIT
            Else
                strFolderPath = CGPath(objFolder.Self.Path)

                ' /* Go through each item in the selection. */
                For Each objItem In selItems
                    lCountEachItem = objItem.Attachments.Count

                    ' /* If the current item contains attachments. */
                    If lCountEachItem > 0 Then
                        Set atmts = objItem.Attachments

                        ' /* Go through each attachment in the current item. */
                        For Each atmt In atmts

                            ' Get the full name of the current attachment.
                            strAtmtFullName = atmt.FileName

                            ' Find the dot postion in atmtFullName.
                            intDotPosition = InStrRev(strAtmtFullName, ".")

                            ' Get the name.
                            strAtmtName(0) = Left$(strAtmtFullName, intDotPosition - 1)
                            ' Get the file extension.
                            strAtmtName(1) = Right$(strAtmtFullName, Len(strAtmtFullName) - intDotPosition)
                            ' Get the full saving path of the current attachment.
                            strAtmtPath = strFolderPath & atmt.FileName

                            ' /* If the length of the saving path is not larger than 260 characters.*/
                            If Len(strAtmtPath) <= MAX_PATH Then
                                ' True: This attachment can be saved.
                                blnIsSave = True

                                ' /* Loop until getting the file name which does not exist in the folder. */
                                Do While objFSO.FileExists(strAtmtPath)
                                    strAtmtNameTemp = strAtmtName(0) & _
                                                      Format(Now, "_mmddhhmmss") & _
                                                      Format(Timer * 1000 Mod 1000, "000")
                                    strAtmtPath = strFolderPath & strAtmtNameTemp & "." & strAtmtName(1)

                                    ' /* If the length of the saving path is over 260 characters.*/
                                    If Len(strAtmtPath) > MAX_PATH Then
                                        lCountEachItem = lCountEachItem - 1
                                        ' False: This attachment cannot be saved.
                                        blnIsSave = False
                                        Exit Do
                                    End If
                                Loop

                                ' /* Save the current attachment if it is a valid file name. */
                                If blnIsSave Then atmt.SaveAsFile strAtmtPath
                            Else
                                lCountEachItem = lCountEachItem - 1
                            End If
                        Next
                    End If

                    ' Count the number of attachments in all Outlook items.
                    lCountAllItems = lCountAllItems + lCountEachItem
                Next
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "Failed to get the handle of Outlook window!", vbCritical, "Error from Attachment Saver"
            blnIsEnd = True
            GoTo PROC_EXIT
        End If

    ' /* For run-time error:
    '    The Explorer has been closed and cannot be used for further operations.
    '    Review your code and restart Outlook. */
    Else
        MsgBox "Please select an Outlook item at least.", vbExclamation, "Message from Attachment Saver"
        blnIsEnd = True
    End If

PROC_EXIT:
    SaveAttachmentsFromSelection = lCountAllItems

    ' /* Release memory. */
    If Not (objFSO Is Nothing) Then Set objFSO = Nothing
    If Not (objItem Is Nothing) Then Set objItem = Nothing
    If Not (selItems Is Nothing) Then Set selItems = Nothing
    If Not (atmt Is Nothing) Then Set atmt = Nothing
    If Not (atmts Is Nothing) Then Set atmts = Nothing

    ' /* End all code execution if the value of blnIsEnd is True. */
    If blnIsEnd Then End
End Function

' #####################
' Convert general path.
' #####################
Public Function CGPath(ByVal Path As String) As String
    If Right(Path, 1) <> "\" Then Path = Path & "\"
    CGPath = Path
End Function

' ######################################
' Run this macro for saving attachments.
' ######################################
Public Sub ExecuteSaving()
    Dim lNum As Long

    lNum = SaveAttachmentsFromSelection

    If lNum > 0 Then
        MsgBox CStr(lNum) & " attachment(s) was(were) saved successfully.", vbInformation, "Message from Attachment Saver"
    Else
        MsgBox "No attachment(s) in the selected Outlook items.", vbInformation, "Message from Attachment Saver"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to dims

```
Dim SndrName            As String
```

then this `SndrName = objItem.SenderName & "_"` next to

```
          For Each objItem In selItems
                lCountEachItem = objItem.Attachments.Count
                SndrName = objItem.SenderName & "_"  ' <--- Add this
```

and change the saveas

```
                      ' Get the full saving path of the current attachment.
                        strAtmtPath = strFolderPath & SndrName & atmt.FileName '
```

Answer (score 1):

```
strAtmtPath = strFolderPath & objItem.SenderEmailAddress & "-" & atmt.FileName
```